# Passing function-callback in seperate SDKs (e.g. Facebook-SDK)

Tags: facebook, ember.js, facebook-javascript-sdk, ember-cli

In a previous question I descriped my confusing about debuging JS in a proper way.

Now I need some help in handling a specific usecase.

Im trying to develop an ember-application which is able to loginto facebook using the facebook-sdk. Therefore I generated an component which places a button into the dom and react to the click. Look at this please:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({

  actions: {
    loginintofb: function() {
      console.log("loginintofb");
      FB.login(this.checkLoginState);
    }
  },

  checkLoginState: function() {
    console.log("checkLoginState"); // --> output | component.js:15
    //statusChangeCallback(response) //--> is not defined | also sdk.js:95 (???)
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {

      // ##### HERE Ive got problems! #####
      statusChangeCallback(response); // --> is not defined | sdk.js:95

    });
  },

  statusChangeCallback: function(response) {
    console.log('statusChangeCallback');
    console.log(response);
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
      ...
    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
      ...
    } else {
      ...
    }
  }


});
```

The problem is the commented line: Iv have to pass an function call as a callback-handler to the facebook api. So in other words: Iam in the ember coomponent context --> going to the facebook-api --> wants to call a function back in the component.

As you may already metioned: The browser calls me, that `statusChangeCallback(response);` is not a function. So the place where the browser will call the function (within the Facebook-SDK I quess) is out of the scope of that function.

Also: When putting the call `statusChangeCallback()` right under the `console.log("checkLoginState");` (see comment *--> is not defined*), the browser says that statusChangeCallback is not defined! The strange thing is: The terminal says, that thes reference error came from sdk.js but the line over that 
one (the *console.log(...)*) came from component.js. Ho could that be?

How can I ged rid of that? Can anybody help me please with that "scope"-based-problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 separate issues here.

1. To refer to `statusChangeCallback` you need to do it off the object.
2. The context is different in the callback.

Consider this:

```
checkLoginState: function() {
  // This will display undefined:
  console.log(statusChangeCallback);
  // this will display the function:
  console.log(this.statusChangeCallback);

  // This will work:
  FB.getLoginStatus(response => {
    this.statusChangeCallback(response);
  });
},
```

The [fat arrow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) from [es2015](/questions/tagged/es2015) means that the inner scope is inherited from the parent `checkLoginState`.

We can simplify what you're trying to do though. Either:

```
checkLoginState: function() {
  FB.getLoginStatus(this.statusChangeCallback);
}
```

Or if you want the context of `statusChangeCallback` to remain on the component, bind it:

```
checkLoginState: function() {
  FB.getLoginStatus(this.statusChangeCallback.bind(this));
}
```

In an as-of-yet uncertain future of [es7](/questions/tagged/es7) there's a bind proposal that'll simplify it to (don't use this until it's out of [experimental babel](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/experimental/)):

```
checkLoginState: function() {
  FB.getLoginStatus(::this.statusChangeCallback);
}
```

Comment: GREAT! Thats exactly what I was looking for! I even  didn't know the fat arrow-syntax  yet. Good think, thank you for that

Comment: @MarcM Have a look through: https://babeljs.io/docs/learn-es2015/ all of these things work with ember.js when you're using ember-cli. javascript is a lot more fun to write when you can use es2015.